# How to view "calculated when request is sent" headers in Postman

Tags: https, postman

In Postman, there are some auto-generated headers, that are only **calculated when request is sent**. Is there a way to view their values after the request is sent?

[image]

Comment: What Headers are you looking for? Can you the question with more details about the request and the Headers you're setting.

Comment: I want to know what Content-Length is calculated to. This doesn't show in Console or Log Request Headers like the other calculated ones do.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you open the Postman Console, it's the 3rd icon on bottom left side of the app, this will show you the details of the request and response.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/debugging-and-logs/

Comment: Although some of the header's values showed up, some others are still missing.

Comment: For some reason, Content-Length doesn't show in the console "log" Request Headers, even though it's "<calculated when request is sent>", like others that do show are, like Host or Postman-Token. I can't tell what the actual calculated Content-Length is, and I can't tell if that value or lack of it is causing the error.

Answer (score 18):

Click on **Console** menu. it will give you detailed information about your request.
[image]

Comment: If you cannot find the console as depicted, press `ALT+CTRL+C` or go to `View` > `Show Postman Console`. Then click on the request row and choose `Headers`.